# Optics: finding total power of a system, including wavelength

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, wavelength

Specifically I need to create an ABCD matrix given 2 radii of curvatures, the thickness of the lens, type of glass (BK7) and a given wavelength. I will have to figure this out eventually, so help would be appreciated with this as well, but my main question is, how do I correlate the wavelength of the incident light to the total power? If I have the wavelength of light, how do I decide what the power of the lens is if nothing in the lens changes, just the wavelength of the beam of light (for example, how would the power differ if a yellow helium line was shone, or a blue hydrogen line)?

Thank you!

Comment: The refractive index of the glass is actually wavelength-dependent.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation